# git - shared repository sgid

Tags: git, permissions, git-bare

I'm using a `bare` `sharedRepository` to allow a group of developers to push.

In order to keep the good file group on pushes, I changed SGID of `objects`

```
$ sudo chmod -R g+s my_repository/objects
```

If it really is the right way to do, should I change the SGID of any other directories (`branches`, `refs`, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your other question I suggested changing at least `refs`.  Based on the git repository layout documentation [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html) I don't think just changing `objects` and `refs` is enough.  You'll need to change this setting on any directory which contains a file that could be changed by a push.

Comment: Thank you for the doc link, I'll first try with `objects` & `refs` and see if it keeps doing the job.